# comma in console.log (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, string, var, console.log

This might be an stupid question but I don't get it. I really hope I don't get down votes

When I try and run this code

```
var mydate= new Date (19995,10,5);
console.log("foo was born on the day :" mydate.getDay());
```

in firebug (Mozeilla) I get an error( SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list), though when I add the comma between the string and the variable like that :

```
var mydate= new Date (19995,10,5);
console.log("foo was born on the day :", mydate.getDay());
```

it works. why do I need to add the comma ?

Comment: Whomever voted to close this as off-topic because of a typographical error is wrong, this is a "syntax" question, although similar they are very different. Good question +1

Comment: I  do not really get that a lot here. Thanks @AdamBuchananSmith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use commas when we're passing an arguments and console.log take those arguments, merge them together and print output.

Comment: So this is just restricted for console.log ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Console/log  
Yes, because it's a function (a method, in deeper meaning) you pass arguments, so you separate them with commas. If you want to do string concat (join, put together), you need to use '+'.

Example:  

`var name = 'John';  
var str = "Hi, my name is " + name;`

Comment: So it is as if I'm passing parameters to a function like function my Function(  X , Y) { //foo Code }

Comment: Yes, where X and Y can be string or variable

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the + operator instead of the comma as in the example below.

```
console.log("foo was born on the day: " + maydate.getDay());
```

This also works with variables/etc. Like in the example below. You can also add another + operator after the variable to continue with the text.

```
console.log("foo is " + fooAge + " years old");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a '+' to concatenate:

```
console.log("foo was born on the day :" + maydate.getDay());
```